# Is there something comparable to #pragma message?

Tags: c#, pragma

I am working with a project that uses both c++ and c#.  I've been working on a huge messy integration and have been making heavy use of #pragma message to call out code that isn't fully functional yet (broken as a result of the integration).  This is a really nice way to clutter up the build log so it's easy to find things that need to be fixed up.  The problem is that I can't find anything that will work the same way for c#.

I don't want to use the obsolete attribute, that's not at all what I'm looking for.  I tried #warn, but that just generates a "warning as error" which fails the build.  Again, not what I'm looking for (I could just use #error if I wanted to fail the build...).

For now I'm just putting my messages in comments that can be searched for, but this requires some knowledge of what to look for as well as the motivation to look for it.  Calling issues out with a custom message in the build log is much preferable as it's hard to ignore!

My research leads me to believe that there isn't a way to do what I want but I wanted to see if you experts agree with me or not.  :)

Comment: The thing Microsoft would like you to do is to create Team Foundation Server items for everything you want to touch later. I don't know if there is a way to do it directly in code, sorry.

Comment: Like @LB2 said, what's wrong with `#warning`. For me it does exactly that, produce a warning; not failing the build.

Comment: #warning does not fail the build.  It only produces a warning during build.

Comment: @Erik You can configure the project to `treat warnings as errors` if you want all warnings to act as errors (should work with #warning).

Comment: My fingers faster than my eyes - didn't see that you already tried it.  Why is warning failing the build for you?  Do you have `treat warnings as errors` turned on?  Do you have some sort of custom build procedure that causes warnings to fail?  If not `#warning` should work...

Comment: `#warning` would fail the build if `-pedantic-errors` (or its equivalent) is enabled. @thehelix Why not just use a special comment prefix? I generally use `//TODO: something something something` for anything I have to do later, and then searching for `//TODO` will find all my notes. As a bonus, it seems that most to-do lists that leave notes in code use similar syntax.

Comment: The C# way is to throw a NotImplementedException.  Just as easy to search for and harder to ignore.  And yes, //TODO works well, better than it does in C++ which only shows these comments when you open the source file in the editor.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sticking with //TODO for now I guess.  We do treat warnings as errors, but this isn't something I can change for this project.  But now I know for the future.  :)

Answer (score 8):

I typically use the following code:

```
#warning //Todo Finish this method by....
```

`#warning` does not have to be treated as an error, it is configurable in each project under Project Configuration | Build Tab:

[image]

With the description in the warning the build log should look like the following:

[image]

Additionally, the `//Todo` comment will add the description to the built-in task list which allows you to distinguish between compiler warnings and user-set compiler warnings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`#warning` does exactly what you want: produce a compile warning. This does not fail the build.

Maybe you have the setting enabled to treat warnings as errors? This setting can be found on your Project Configuration | Build tab.

Comment: The problem is, when you get someone else's project with more than a thousand warnings, your user-defined warning won't do the job.

Comment: @Szybki If you get lots of warnings in C# then probably you have bigger problems. Furthermore, Warnings are there to warn you, so if you're starting to miss warnings because of their amount then any warning is useless, not just the user #pragma ones, and, again, you have bigger problems.